TV show (?) involving two astronauts on another planet trying to get to a wrecked ship (?) with a sand snake swimming around
I think it's black and white. I think the scene is two astronauts on a crashed lander and they're trying to get to another wrecked ship (maybe). There is a sand snake that is swimming around and they have to figure out how to get to point B.
Maybe it was a TV show? I don't remember much else.

Once you've been chomped by a sand snake, you've had it!

Is this "The Invisible Enemy" (1964), S2.E7 of The Outer Limits (1963–1965)...?

The first manned expedition to Mars finds itself being killed one-by-one by an alien predator.

The plot involves four astronauts sent to Mars to investigate the disappearance of two astronauts during a prior mission. They learn that the astronauts were killed by a huge snake-like alien swimming beneath the planet's sandy surface and confront the beast themselves.




Those "sand beasts" are a LOT like the ones in the Tremors movie, with the same hiding on rocks and attracted to vibrations... and similar to the sandworms in Beetlejuice and Dune... interesting theme

The "sand snake" sounds like a black and white episode of the 1960s series The OUter Limits (1963-1965), specifically "The Invisible Enemy", seaosn 2 episode 7, October 31, 1964. Based loosely on Jerry Sohl's short story "The Invisible Enemy" from Imaginative Tales, September 1955.
Two astronauts on the M-1 missin to Mars died transmitting screams back to Earth in 2021. Mars-2 lands nearby 3 years later (in 2024).  And they also have problems with an unseen enemy in the sand.
It is common to call the unseen enemy "sand sharks". But my family called the tiny, minnow-like fish that sometimes swam in shallow water at the beach "sand sharks", so I preferred to call the unseen enemy "loam sharks".

Enemy Mine (1985)
Similar plot, just one "man" is actually an alien. And sand "worm" is just a tongue of bigger monster
Trailer:

Welcome to Sci Fi & Fantasy! Unfortunately, "here is another story that's sort of similar to the one you're interested in" is not an appropriate answer to the question (thus will attract downvotes). (The only counterexample might be if no-one had come up with a good match and you thought the OP might have misremembered some details ...)
